# Update query having inner query referencing same table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
update goods_inward_outward
set is_active = 0
where gi_go_id IN (select gi_go_id from goods_inward_outward where gi_go_id <100)
```

I m getting following error.

> **#1093 - You can't specify target table 'goods_inward_outward' for update in FROM clause**

Whats is the problem in above ?
Is this because i am using update and select query on same table?
If so, what can be alternative solving ?

Thanks

Comment: Adding alisas is not solving the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this in MySQL is to use a `join`.  However, in your case, the `join` key and the `where` clause are using the same column.  So, no additional table reference is necessary:

```
update goods_inward_outward gio
    set is_active = 0
    where gi_go_id < 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Would there be anything wrong with doing away with the subquery:

```
UPDATE goods_inward_outward
SET is_active = 0
WHERE gi_go_id < 100
```